# Dynamic Row Count in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi guys I'm trying to count the number of towers in a master property.. but i having problems resetting the count. I only have this code.

```
SELECT ProjectName,T.TowerName ,
           CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),RIGHT('00'+CAST(rank() OVER (ORDER BY T.TowerID) AS VARCHAR(3)),2)) AS TowerID   
FROM MasterProperty AS MP 
INNER JOIN Tower AS T ON Mp.MasterPropertyID = T.MasterPropertyID
```

This is what got.

[image: This is what got.]

This what i need.

[image: This what i need]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` window function:

```
select
    t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by ProjectName order by TowerId) whatIwant
from your_table t;
```